# Pandas - Get last non Nan value plus count number of non Nan in column on a rolling basis

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with the following structure: Date and Trigger. There will a couple of hundreds of rows of data. Here is just a sample:

| id | Date | Trigger |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15/05/2021 | Nan |
| 2 | 16/05/2021 | 1 |
| 3 | 17/05/2021 | 1 |
| 4 | 18/05/2021 | Nan |
| 5 | 19/05/2021 | Nan |
| 6 | 20/05/2021 | 1 |
| 7 | 21/05/2021 | Nan |
| 8 | 22/05/2021 | Nan |

................

I need to solve a few problems.

Problem 1:

I need to add a column, let's name it DST (days since trigger) where I want to calculate for each row, how many days ago (days are consecutive, so we can use the row index as a simple subtraction) was the last trigger (not Nan value).

The result should be like this:

| id | Date | Trigger | DST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15/05/2021 | Nan | Nan |
| 2 | 16/05/2021 | 1 | Nan |
| 3 | 17/05/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 18/05/2021 | Nan | 1 |
| 5 | 19/05/2021 | Nan | 2 |
| 6 | 20/05/2021 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 21/05/2021 | Nan | 1 |
| 8 | 22/05/2021 | Nan | 2 |

So for each row in DST column, we look upwards in the Trigger column and find last non Nan value.

Problem 2:

I need to calculate in a new column (DC), for how many consecutive days the trigger happened.

The result should be like this:

| id | Date | Trigger | DST | DC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15/05/2021 | Nan | Nan | 0 |
| 2 | 16/05/2021 | 1 | Nan | 1 |
| 3 | 17/05/2021 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 18/05/2021 | Nan | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 19/05/2021 | Nan | 2 | 0 |
| 6 | 20/05/2021 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 21/05/2021 | Nan | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 22/05/2021 | Nan | 2 | 0 |

The zeros can also be Nan (it doesn't bother me). The difference in search to the problem 1, is that here we start counting from current row (in problem 1 we were searching from the row above upwards)

Problem 3:

Add another column where I count how many days in the last 3 days the trigger was 1:

The result should be like this:

| id | Date | Trigger | DST | DC | 3D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15/05/2021 | Nan | Nan | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 16/05/2021 | 1 | Nan | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 17/05/2021 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 18/05/2021 | Nan | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 19/05/2021 | Nan | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 20/05/2021 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 21/05/2021 | Nan | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | 22/05/2021 | Nan | 2 | 0 | 1 |

So we look upwards 3 rows (including current row) and count how many 1s are on the trigger column (for the first 3 values we only consider the available number of rows above them).

Hope that makes sense.

Is there any way I can calculate this in a simple way, without going through row by row iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute DST and DC we want to use `cumsum` and `cumcount` on `GroupBy` groups, so the counts reset. To do this let’s first define groups that restart at every day with trigger:

```
>>> dstgroups = df['Trigger'].notna().cumsum()
>>> dstgroups
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
Name: Trigger, dtype: int64
>>> df['Trigger'].groupby(dstgroups).cumcount()
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    0
6    1
7    2
dtype: int64
```

Now that’s roughly what you want except for some strange semantics, in particular:

- `NaN` until day after first trigger
- count a day with trigger as adding to the delay

But we can easily tweak that, respectively by `mask`ing with a `cummax()`, and by shifting and adding `1`:

```
>>> df['Trigger'].groupby(dstgroups).cumcount()\
...     .where(df['Trigger'].fillna(0).cummax().astype(bool))\
...     .shift().add(1)
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    3.0
6    1.0
7    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Same with `DC`, but reset at every day without trigger and no unexpected tweaks, also we use `cumsum` instead of `cumcount`:

```
>>> dcgroups = df['Trigger'].isna().cumsum()
>>> df['Trigger'].fillna(0).groupby(dcgroups).cumsum()
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    1.0
6    0.0
7    0.0
Name: Trigger, dtype: float64
```

To compute 3D it’s much simpler, we can just use a rolling window:

```
>>> df['Trigger'].eq(1).rolling(3, center=False, min_periods=1).sum()
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
7    1.0
Name: Trigger, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you! It does the job great. Well done!